# sql date format order dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, format

I am using this code to format date with SQL:

```
convert(VARCHAR, DT, 20)
```

The output is:

```
2016-01-01 20:40:12
```

But how do I get the day first.

I would like to get: dd-mm-yyyy:

```
01-01-2016 20:40:12
```

When I look in this table: 
http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/sqldatetimeformats.aspx 
I do not see this formatting.

Thx!

Comment: what SQL engine are you using?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For **dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss**

```
  (CONVERT(varchar, DT, 103) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, DT, 108)) AS MyEuropeanDate
```

For **dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss**

```
  (CONVERT(varchar, DT, 105) + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, DT, 108)) AS MyEuropeanDate
```

And to understand it right for the next time, look at the official doc that Gordon wisely linked in the comments :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Could not find a native tSQL function but you can do something like this:

```
    DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '20160101';

SELECT CASE
         WHEN LEN(CAST(DAY(@Date) AS VARCHAR)) = 1 THEN '0'+CAST(DAY(@Date) AS VARCHAR)
         ELSE CAST(DAY(@Date) AS VARCHAR)
      END
      +'-'+
      CASE
         WHEN LEN(CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR)) = 1 THEN '0'+CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR)
         ELSE CAST(MONTH(@Date) AS VARCHAR)
      END
      +'-'+
      CAST(YEAR(@Date) AS VARCHAR)
      +' '+
      SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Date, 114), 1, 8);
```

OR you can do this:

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '20160101';

SELECT  (REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar, @Date, 103),'/','-') + ' ' + CONVERT(varchar, @Date, 108))
```

RESULT:

[image]

Comment: don't you think you over complicate? :D

Comment: @ThomasG but your solution was not complete. It returned incorrect format

Comment: "was" ? I have not even edited it. Develop what will my solution returns according to you

Comment: actually you was right, OP asked for `dd-mm-yyyy` and I gave `dd/mm/yyyy`. I'll offer both